# How to properly write a solution to the following inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Trying after many years to refresh my calculus and stack at very basic.
I'm following Thomas' Calculus and here is the problem:
Find a domain and a range for the following function:
$$f(t)=\frac{2}{t^2-16}$$

Domain I've found:
$D\in{\{t|(-\infty,-4)\cup(-4,4)\cup(4, \infty)\}}$, but I struggle with finding or more exactly **write it in an understandable way** steps to find a range.

To simplify range is a
$(-\infty,-\frac{1}{8}]\cup(0, \infty)$ but why? In an explanation which I had found said that
$t < -4 \Rightarrow t^2 - 16 > 0 \Rightarrow \frac{2}{t^2-16}>0$ but I feel that few steps here are skipped.

Can somebody write a detailed response for this part?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you questioning the assertion that $t < -4 \implies t^2 - 16  > 0 \implies \frac{2}{t^2 - 16} > 0$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, yes

Comment: You have a formula for $f(x)$ which has no $x$ in it, only a $t.$

Comment: @coffeemath, it's a typo, I've fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$t^2\ge0\implies t^2-16\in[-16,\infty).$$

As the expression can change sign we decompose before we can take the reciprocal

$$t^2-16\in[-16,0)\cup(0,\infty)\implies\frac2{t^2-16}\in\left(-\infty,\frac2{-16}\right]\cup(0,\infty).$$

[image]

Comment: I apologize, but I still struggling to get how you took the last step, reciprocal inequation? Can you please explain it a little bit? Thank you.

Comment: @Anatoly: take the reciprocal.

Comment: Why $[-16,0)$ becomes $(-\infty, \frac{2}{-16}$] ?

Comment: @Anatoly: because you take $2/x$. Think about $2/(-16), 2/(-15), 2/(-14.2), 2/(-0.001)\cdots$

Comment: You mean $2/t$? I think I got it, need some time to digest, thank you.

Comment: @Anatoly: $t$ is already used.

Comment: No, I still don't get why $(-\infty, \frac{2}{-16})$, why $-\infty$? $\frac{2}{0} = \infty$?

Comment: @Anatoly: $$\frac2{0^-}$$

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is an even function, so choosing either $(-\infty,-4)\cup(-4,0]$ or $[0,4)\cup(4+\infty)$ for the range calculation is sufficient. I'll choose the latter.

Let the range of $f$ be $R$. It's easy to show that $f$ is decreasing when $t\in(4,+\infty)$. For $\forall c\in\mathbb{R}_+$, one solves
$$\dfrac{2}{t^2-16}=c$$
for $t$ and finds $t=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{c}+16}\in(4,+\infty)$, so for any positive number there exists some $t\in D$ which satisfies $f(t)=c$, i.e. $R\supseteq\mathbb{R}_+$.

The same process goes for $t\in[0,4)$ and you will find the remaining part of $R$ being $(-\infty,-\dfrac{1}{8}]$.