# Finding the range of given function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Find the range of $f(x) = \frac{2}{x^2 -16}$

I found that the domain is $(-\infty,-4) \cup(-4,4) \cup (4, \infty)$. Then tried to find the range case by case

$1.$case : if $-\infty <x<-4$ , then $16 <x^2 < \infty$ ,

$0 <x^2 -16 < \infty \rightarrow 0 <\frac{x^2 -16}{2} < \infty \rightarrow \frac{1}{\infty} < \frac{2}{x^2 -16} < \frac{1}{0} = 0 < \frac{2}{x^2 -16} < \infty $

$2.$case : if $-4 <x < 4$ , then $0 \leq x^2 <16$,

$-16 \leq x^2 -16 <0 \rightarrow -8 \leq \frac{x^2 -16}{2} <0 \rightarrow -8\geq \frac{2}{x^2 -16} >0$ but this case is impossible because it cannot be $0 <f(x) \leq -8$

$3.$case : $4<x<\infty$ , then $16 <x^2 < \infty \rightarrow 0< x^2 -16 < \infty \rightarrow 0< \frac{x^2 -16}{2}< \infty \rightarrow \frac{1}{\infty} < \frac{2}{x^2 -16} < \frac{1}{0} \rightarrow 0< f(x) <\infty$

So  the only range i found is $(0,\infty)$ , but the answer is $$\bigg(-\infty ,\frac{-1}{8}\bigg) \cup \bigg(0,\infty\bigg)$$

There is a solution for general in here : [How to properly write a solution to the following inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770888/how-to-properly-write-a-solution-to-the-following-inequality)

However i am interested in "what am i missing" ? Is my solution way not correct ?

Comment: Consider as $x\to4^-$, we approach $-\infty$, and for $-4\lt x\lt 4$, the negative range, we attain our maximum at $x=0,f(x)=-\frac{1}{8}$

Answer (score 1):

Lets say $$y = \frac{2}{x^2 -16}$$

Now , write $y$ in terms of $x$ such that $$x = \sqrt{\frac{2+16y}{y}}$$

we know that $\frac{2+16y}{y} \geq 0$ because of root square and $y \neq0$ because of denominator , so by solving this in equality we found that $$y \in (-\infty , -1/8] \cup (0, \infty )$$

Comment: Check the endpoints.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig my inattention , edited , thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with your solution because:

$$-8 \leq \frac{x^2 -16}{2} <0 \rightarrow \color{red}{-8}\geq \frac{2}{x^2 -16} >0$$
isn't exact (it cannot be a $\color{red}{-8}$)

Anyhow, I wouldn't write this solution as you have done but in the following manner.

Let us look for values of $y$ that are in the range of $f$, i.e., that are such that there exists an $x$ such that:

$$y=\dfrac{2}{x^2-16} \ \iff \ x^2=\frac{2}{y}+16=2\frac{1+8y}{y}\tag{1}$$

The important fact now is that this quotient $N/D$ has the same sign as the product $ND$:

$$q(y):=y(1+8y)=8y^2+y$$

It is well known that a quadratic with positive dominant coefficient (here $8$) with real roots $-1/8$ and $0$ is

- negative in the interval between the roots $I=(-1/8,0)$;
- positive or zero outside this interval $I$.

and this is the last condition which is interesting (being outside $(-1/8;0)$) because, according to (1), it is to be equal to a square, which is positive.

It remains to consider the limit cases.